# IOS unable to play audio data

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am recieving buffer data from my server;

```
    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)]; //Getting data from server
    if (len > 0) {
            NSData *audioData = [[NSData alloc]initWithBytes:buffer length:len];
                if (nil != audioData) {


        [[mainSounds alloc]initSounds:audioData];

        }
}
```

now my **mainSounds** class

```
-(id)initSounds : (NSData *)  audioData{

    NSError *error;
    testAudioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:&error];
     NSLog(@"Player played %d and error %@",[testAudioPlayer play],[error userInfo]);

    return self;

}
```

i also played a static audio file it works fine and sound played.
giving NSLog -> player played 1

but when i tried my server data then it says player played 0 and error { }

i check the NSData from server in NSLog

```
AUDIO DATA <6f06af08 b209cd09 0a0aed0a 000c870c 6f0c5b0c dc0cc70d 820ec00e cc0e270f f20fd710 5d117b1c 6136013f aa28c112 050d070b 291b1235 812faf14 8e0a050b 18080a>
```

is their any problem in my NSData ..

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: audioData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSData *finalDATA = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[mainSounds alloc]initSounds: finalDATA];
```

And in your `initSounds` method

```
NSError *error;
testAudioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:finalDATA error:&error];
[testAudioPlayer play];
```

Comment: This is what i got after trying above code.'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: First check your `audioData` is nil or not >?

Comment: @shujatAli - try with NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: buffer length: len freeWhenDone:YES];